# Ensuring Windows 10 computer joins correct subnet via DHCP

Tags: dhcp, windows-10

I'm setting up a proxy/firewall and I want it to be the DHCP server for windows clients. The problem is that if I set DHCP to automatic on the windows clients, they will sometimes select the network's modem as their DHCP server instead and join the wrong subnet. Obviously if I set the IP address configuration manually, it's not an issue - it will always choose the proxy DHCP and join the correct subnet.

How do I ensure that the windows clients always use the proxy's DHCP server instead of the modem's?

I know that this just works in an Active Directory domain with its own DHCP Server without the modem "hijacking" domain computers.

I just can't work out how to do it outside of an Active Directory domain

Comment: Have you checked in your modem if you can specify a dhcp server in the network settings. If there are two devices doing dhcp offers it's a random ping pong between them. I would also recommend OPNSense, that also offers a DHCP server, but it's also offers a firewall, that way you might be able to block the dhcp traffic from your modem using a firewall rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I ensure that the windows clients always use the proxy's DHCP server instead of the modem's?

You should *not* have two DHCP servers on a network. There's no way for clients to know which DHCP server is legitimate and not.

Disable DHCP server on your modem.

> I know that this just works in an Active Directory domain with its own DHCP Server without the modem "hijacking" domain computers.

It doesn't. AD is unrelated to DHCP. Windows clients will happily accept IP's that has no route to reach the DC's, and they'll happily accept any DHCP server not affiliated with the domain.